# How to Add and Set up accessory using HMAccessoryPayLoad

Tags: ios, macos, homekit, ios-homekit

I want to know how to use

[apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/hmhome/2941039-addandsetupaccessories)

> `func addAndSetupAccessories(with payload: HMAccessorySetupPayload, 
>        completionHandler completion: @escaping ([HMAccessory]?, Error?) -> Void)`

I want to use this func because I need to pair HomeKit accessory without QR code or the HomeKit code.  I want to pair the accessory through code.

the documentation of HMAccessorySetupPayload argument for the above function, it says it accepts URL for init.

I scanned QR-code for an accessory with QR code reader, it showed some type of URL as 
**`X-HM://00671I5XXXXXX`**

can some help me how to pair the accessory with this function.

Comment: How did you added ? i have same scenario.

Comment: I would like to know how it works. Please let me know if you resolved, i'm trying to add it in same way i need to add it in background without opening native homekit camera. Thanks.

Comment: Have added new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62470261/how-to-add-homekit-accessory-using-hmaccessorypayload